# Accessing Elements of a Tuple

Tags: python, tuples

I am accessing an element of length 2 tuple by `tuple_name[0]` but the python interpreter keeps giving me error `Index out of bounds`.

Here is the code for reference:

```
def full(mask):
    v = True
    for i in mask:
        if i == 0:
            v = False
    return v

def increment(mask, l):
    i = 0
    while (i < l) and (mask[i] == 1):
        mask[i] = 0
        i = i+1
    if i < l:
        mask[i] = 1

def subset(X,Y):
    s = len(X)
    mask = [0 for i in range(s)]
    yield []
    while not full(mask):
        increment(mask, s)
        i = 0
        yield ([X[i] for i in range(s) if mask[i]] , [Y[i] for i in range(s) if mask[i]])

x = [100,12,32]
y = ['hello','hero','fool']

s = subset(x,y)  # s is generator

for a in s:
    print a[0]   # Python gives me error here saying that index out of 
                 # bounds, but it runs fine if I write "print a".
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changing the final line to simply `print a` and running the exact code you've pasted above, I get the following output:

```
[]
([100], ['hello'])
([12], ['hero'])
([100, 12], ['hello', 'hero'])
([32], ['fool'])
([100, 32], ['hello', 'fool'])
([12, 32], ['hero', 'fool'])
([100, 12, 32], ['hello', 'hero', 'fool'])
```

So, quite clearly, the first iteration is an empty list, so does **not** have an element 0.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing you yield from `subset` is the empty list, `yield []`.

Naturally you can't access an element on that which is why `a[0]` fails.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that `subset` yields is the empty list:

```
def subset(X,Y):
    ...
    yield []
    ...
```

This is what's tripping up the `a[0]`.

You probably meant to `yield ([],[])` to keep the first value consistent with the rest.